# Permutations with team captains taking turns picking teammates

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For counting/permutation problems, what if you had 10 people who were playing volleyball, and 2 of them were team captains. The team captains take turns picking teammates. How would you calculate this? I'm guessing you would use the Fundamental Counting Principle. For team captain A, this would be (8)(6)(4)(2)=384, since he's taking turns with team captain B, whose possible choices would be (7)(5)(3)(1)=105. Would you keep these answers separate? Or would you multiply them together to find the total number of possibilities? (In which case it is just 8!...) Or am I just way off?
Thanks

Comment: What are you counting? Different possible pairs of teams? Different sequences of picks?

Comment: I guess different possible teams (order not important) with this "picking" technique of back and forth.

Comment: Would the answer be any different if captain A made four choices and B got the other four?  Would it be any different if names were picked out of a hat without looking?

Comment: Maybe it would be the same... looking at the overall result? Would my thought process only matter if I were considering the teams separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up real life situations, and combinatorics.

Once you say that A and B choose turn by turn, they wouldn't be random choices. A would pick what (in A's opinion) was the best person to pick, B would then pick up what for B was the best person to pick from the remaining, and so on.

*So if choices were clear, there would be only one way of picking the two teams*

On the other hand, if choices were arbitrary, (pure combinatorics ) you might as well just form a team for A, $\binom84$ and that for B would be the remainder

Comment: @Hannah, if you are satisfied with the answer, you should close the question with a tick if you are entitled to. And if not satisfied, you should raise your doubts.